# How to make background-image fade using JavaScript without jQuery?

Tags: javascript

I'm success to use pure JavaScript to make background images fade in/out, but (1)how to make background image show first and start to fade in/out without white part? (2) making background image stay in div block?  stuck in here for a week.

I'm trying to using onload event and CSS background-image but both don't work, CSS will make image keep stay in there.

HTML:

```
  <div id="fade"> <span class="bg">Front-Learning</span>   </div>
```

JavaScipt: (before)

```
var bgslide = [
    'image/rotate-img-1.jpg',
    'image/rotate-img-2.jpg',
    'image/rotate-img-3.jpg'
    ];
bg_len = 0;
backgroundSlideshow = function bg1() {
    if (bg_len == bgslide.length) bg_len = 0;
    document.body.style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + bgslide[bg_len++] + ')';
    document.body.style.backgroundRepeat ="no-repeat";
    document.body.style.backgroundSize = "cover";
    document.body.style.backgroundPosition ="center";
    document.body.style.height = "400 px";
    document.body.style.minWidth = "1000px";
}
window.setInterval(backgroundSlideshow,3000);
window.backgroundImage='url(' + bgslide[0] + ')';
window.onload = document.body.style.backgroundImage='url(' + bgslide[be_len] + ')';
```

JavaScript (after); it works and what I expect for, but I don't know what the different.

```
 bg_len = 0;
   backgroundSlideshow = function () {
       if (bg_len == bgslide.length) bg_len = 0;
       let fade=document.getElementById("fade");
       fade.style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + bgslide[bg_len++] + ')';
   }
   window.setInterval(backgroundSlideshow,3000);
   window.onload = backgroundSlideshow;
```

Comment: What do you mean with "without white part"?

Comment: I set setIntervel is 3 secs so when I open website, it will show white background first, and I don't know how to adjust it.

Comment: You're setting background to body tag, what div do you mean? can you post your HTML code?